# Is job contract ending similar to being laid off?

Tags: united-states, contracts, legal, layoff

I've been working on a contract for over a year and lately the amount of work available has decreased. I have been paying into unemployment through my contracting company. If the contracting company or the company I'm working at ends my contract would this be similar to being laid off and would I be able to collect unemployment?

Comment: Welcome to the workplace.  In the future, you may not want to pick the best answer right away.  Waiting a few days encourages more people to answer.

Comment: contact your state's unemployment office

Comment: What you are asking for is legal advice and not as much employment "conduct". Please refer to the law exchange group instead.

Comment: @fireshark519 anything that is easily answerable by someone with an HR level of knowledge is on topic, a simple question about unemployment eligibility falls within those parameters

Comment: this would surely depend on your country.  the key element is that if you are a contractor you are **self employed**.  that affects EVERYTHING about your taxes, benefits, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laws can vary from place to place, but in general you are entitled to unemployment benefits unless you leave employment *voluntarily* (subject to other regulations). If you had terminated a contract (or resigned from employment) that is voluntary. If your contract is ended by the other party, or your employment is terminated, that is not voluntary. If you contact whatever organization administers your unemployment benefits they will give you a definitive answer.